# alignment problem in array with display style elements

Tags: arrays, alignment, displaystyle

I am using the following code

```
\[
\begin{array}{rr}
     \displaystyle{\frac{1}{2}}& 5 \\
     \displaystyle{\frac{1}{2}}& \displaystyle{\frac{11}{22}} \\
     \hline
     \displaystyle{\frac{1}{2}}& 5
\end{array}
\]
```

I get the following output on overleaf

[image]

I have two problems with this.
There is no space between the rows and the horizontal line and the fraction is not aligned nicely with the number in the last column.

I would appreciate any suggestions to fix these problems.
I need a solution that works with KaTeX so loading special packages is not possible.

Comment: Few comments: displaystyle does not take arguments; displaystyle + frac = dfrac; instead of hline try midrule from booktabs, it has better build in spacing

Comment: Overleaf did not recognize dfrac, this is why I used displaystyle. As I said in my post, I cannot load packages and \midrule is not supported by KaTeX.

Comment: Note that katex and mathjax are off off topic here are they are not latex based and thus practically any solution we give you will not work in katex or mathjax (katex is even more limited than mathjax). As long as amsmath is loaded  dfrac is available, mathjax supports it, katex probanot.

Comment: I know dfrac, katex supports it. I did not use it because overleaf does not recognize it by default and I am supposed to give a minimal example. With dfrac the result is the same. I can now sort out the line spacing (using  \vphantom{} ), but I still have the horizontal alignment issue.

Comment: `\\[5pt]` instead of `\\ ` works in KaTeX.

Comment: Yes, this indeed works above the line, but I could not use it below the line. I ended up using \vphantom{large{...content...}} just in front of the elements to have a vertical space enough to typeset the formula in a larger font (but the formula of course is typeset normally). I am still not sure why the horizontal alignment breaks with displaystyle. Does displaystyle (or dfrac) add a space around the formula?